# ReloadRowsAtIndexPaths causes bug in simulator

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView that sometimes has to reload an individual row and occasionally the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method does not call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the entire table content disappears. Having checked on an actual device it seems ok and it only happens on the simulator but I am a bit worried about having a production app with this potential problem.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: It may be an issue specific to particular iOS version (and not simulator/device).

Comment: Are you calling beginUpdates and endUpdates on your tableView?

Comment: I did think that could be the case, changed a few IOS versions, I am using 8.4 to build with and have 9.1 installed on the device an xCode version 7.3

Comment: yes I have tried begin and endUpdates to no avail.

Comment: You can check on radar if someone else is having this bug. Otherwise you could check if your datasource is actually empty, or check what numberOfItemsInSection returns. If this does not match up, you could file a radar.

Comment: I use that very often in my app, I guess it's something wrong with your data source rather then Apple bug.

Comment: the datasource calls numberOfRowsInSecions correctly, not sure how else to check if the datasource is operating correctly